# Get implementation of interface method from constructor of implementing class

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to implement the following behaviour: A function that receives a string and another function as argument and returns a string:

```
interface Foo {
  ConditionalColor(color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean): string;
}
```

Now i try to pass the ConditionalColor method into the implementing class by using its constructor:

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {
  ConditionalIconColor(color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean): string;

  constructor(
    ConditionalColor: (color:string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean) => string
  ) {
    this.ConditionalIconColor = ConditionalColor
  }
```

I get an error saying: `Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.`

I don't know if its just a problem with the syntax or if its not possible to do it the way i try to do it. Maybe you have any ideas to help me out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have a design time implementation, you should declare the function as a property.

Also, you have a typo in the function names. I have used the function name "ConditionalColor".

```js
interface IFoo {
  ConditionalColor(color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean): string;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
  constructor(
    ConditionalColor: (color:string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean) => string
  ) {
    this.ConditionalColor = ConditionalColor;
  }

  ConditionalColor: (color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean) => string;
}
```

Notice the difference between your version (first) and mine (second)

```js
ConditionalColor(color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean): string;
```

```js
ConditionalColor: (color: string, condition: (arg: any) => boolean) => string;
```

Yours is attempting to declare a function without a body. Mine is declaring a property that has a type that accepts arguments and returns a value.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, coudn't copy&paste my code properly. But your answer was right and is working as expected. Thank you very much!